# В чём смысл "уступки" выполнения текущего потока иному в QThread?

Tags: c++, qt, многопоточность, qt5

В справке Qt для статического метода `QThread::yieldCurrentThread()` сказано, что можно, как я это понимаю, "уступить" (yield) контекст выполнения текущего потока иному потоку:

> Yields execution of the current thread to another runnable thread, if
>   any. Note that the operating system decides to which thread to switch.

В чём смысл и для каких случаев может быть полезно применение данного метода?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вообще говоря, инструкция `yield` говорит планировщику операционной системы, что в настоящее время потоку не требуется процессорное время и планировщик ***может*** прервать его исполнение до истечения отведённого потоку кванта времени и передать управление другому потоку. Планировщик может проигнорировать это заявление и не передавать управление другому потоку.

Применять можно, например, для увеличения производительности каких-либо рабочих потоков многопоточных приложений, снижая таким образом производительность вспомогательных потоков. Но следует иметь в виду, что производительность возрастёт только в том случае, когда работающих потоков (реально работающих, а не простаивающих!) больше, чем число ядер процессора.

Польза этого, ИМХО, сомнительная и вместо `yield` лично я бы использовал приоритеты потоков. На практике я это не использовал ни разу.

Comment: Будет ли уместно использовать `yield` в том случае, если потоков много (больше, чем ядер у процессора), потоки работают с сетью и уходят в ожидание при отправке запросов? Например, отправил поток запрос, и выполнил `yield` пока ждёт ответ.

Comment: Вряд ли это уместно. Если запрос синхронный, поток всё равно тормознётся системой до прихода ответа. Более того, `yield` в этом случае выполнится уже после прихода ответа. Если запрос асинхронный, то, вероятно, Вы сами тормознёте поток. Кроме того, потоки, работающие с сетью создают обычно небольшую нагрузку на процессор, не выбирая мощности одного ядра. Скажем так - хуже не будет, а будет ли лучше - ХЗ.

Comment: Понял, значит, это не то, что мне нужно. Спасибо.

Comment: @alexis031182, `yield` часто используется в различных lock-free алгоритмах, в той части, где есть spin-lock. Вместо того, чтобы отчаянно висеть на проверке какого-то флага, можно отдать(yield) управление, чтобы не тратить время CPU на пустую проверку.

Comment: @ixSci, спасибо. То есть, как я понимаю, это при использовании блокировок атомарными типами, правильно? А c обычными мьютексами можно добиться какого-то профита от использования `yield`?

Comment: @alexis031182, весь смысл yield в том, чтобы отдать поток, когда Вы видите, что больше в нём не нуждаетесь, но ожидаете, что будете нуждаться в скором времени. При этом, в вашем потоке нет операции, которая сама отдаст поток(какая-нибудь блокирующая I/O). К примеру, жду я в цикле, пока какой-то флаг будет выставлен. Я могу условиться, что буду делать 1000 проверок, а потом буду отдавать поток, чтобы излишне не нагружать CPU. В целом же правило простое: если Вы не знаете, как использовать yield — не используйте. Когда понадобится, Вы всё поймёте :)

Comment: @ixSci, услышал, спасибо :)